# como fazer esta query sql

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query

codigo é PK em ambas

```
tabela1: cliente
codigo, nome, municipio

tabela2: notafiscal
codigo, numerodanota, cod_cliente
```

quero listar dar um count(*) em todas as notafiscal onde cod_cliente.municipio = 10

como executo este sql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você só precisa utilizar o `JOIN` para fazer a ligação entre as tabelas como abaixo:

```
SELECT COUNT(n.codigo)
  FROM cliente c
       INNER JOIN notafiscal n ON n.cod_cliente = c.codigo
 WHERE c.municipio = 10;
```

Answer (score 5):

Basta fazer um join entre as tabelas e especificar o municipio no `WHERE`.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM notafiscal as n 
INNER JOIN clientes as c ON n.cod_cliente =  c.codigo
WHERE c.municipio = 10
```